# proof of geometric probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Show that $P(X= n+x \mid X > n) = P(X=x)$ for $x= 1, 2, 3 \ldots$ and $n = 1, 2, 3\ldots$

---

step 1: use conditional probability. $P(X = n+x ~~\text{and}~~ X > n)/P(X > n)$

Step 2: HOW DOES the numerator $P(X = n+x ~~\text{and}~~ X > n)$ just simplify to $P(X = n+x)$?

Step 3: expand using pmf of geometric distribution. BUT how do you expand the denominator in step 1?

Answer (score 0):

A geometric distribution is that of the count of trials until the first success in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with constant success rate.

Let $X$ be such a count and $p$ be the success rate.

---

> **Step 1:** use conditional probability. P(X = n+x and X > n)/P(X > n)

Yes, and further, by Bayes' Rule: $$\mathsf P(X=n+x\mid X>n)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(X=n+x)\,\mathsf P(X>n\mid X=n+x)}{\mathsf P(X>n)}$$

---

> **Step 2:** HOW DOES the numerator P(X = n+x and X > n) just simplify to P(X = n+x)?

What is the probability that $X>n$ when given that $X=n+x$, for any positive values of $n$ and $x$?

---

> **Step 3:** expand using pmf of geometric distribution. BUT how do you expand the denominator in step 1?

Well we know $\mathsf P(X=k)~=~ (1-p)^{k-1}\:p\:\mathbf 1_{k\in\{1,2,\ldots\}}$ because to obtain a count of $k$ we have $k-1$ consecutive failures and then one success.

In a similar manner we can measure $\mathsf P(X>k)$ because to have a count greater than $k$ we must have at least $k$ consecutive failures.